# How can I make a dijit.form.Select work with multiple items having the same value?

Tags: javascript, widget, dojo

I have a `dijit.form.Select` widget that I'm using to map labels to values. Some labels need to have the same value, but I need to able to differentiate between the labels when a selection is made. Right now the widget's options look something like this:

```
[
    {
        label: "A",
        value: "1",
    },
    {
        label: "B",
        value: "2"
    },
    {
        label: "C",
        value: "2"
    }
],
```

That is done because the form's processing needs to know that 'B' and 'C' both actually mean 2, but I need to perform some different logic on another control when 'B' vs 'C' is selected. I've found that I can `get("displayedValue")` in the `onChange` event handler to get the "displayed" label, but it will always return the **first** option (B) that matches the current value (2) which is **not necessarily what the user selected**.

So, how can I handle the case when multiple labels need to evaluate to the same value while still being able to differentiate between the labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the dijit/form/Select widget `focusNode.textcontent` attribute:

```js
function disaplySelected() {
  document.getElementById("labelContainer").innerHTML = window.sel.focusNode.textContent;
  document.getElementById("valueContainer").innerHTML = window.sel.value;
}

require(["dijit/form/Select", "dojo/_base/window", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Select, win) {
  window.sel = new Select({
    name: "select2",
    options: [
      {label: "A",value: "1"},
      {label: "B",value: "2"},
      {label: "C",value: "2"}
    ],
  });
  window.sel.placeAt(win.body(), "first").startup();
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.1/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
</head>

<body class="claro">
  <p>
    <button onclick="disaplySelected()">Display selected label</button>
    <br/>Selected item label: <span id="labelContainer"></span>
    <br/>Selected item value: <span id="valueContainer"></span>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```